# How do I print a link only if it doesn't lead to access denied

Tags: theming, users, navigation

My nodes have fairly complex permissions set on them.  I want to display a small edit link on the teaser for a specific content type, only if the user has the permissions required to edit that specific node.  I already customise the display with the file node--newsletter.tpl.php

I tried:

```
<?php
$quick_links['quick-edit'] = array(
    'title' => 'Edit',
    'href' => 'node/' . $nid . '/edit');
?>
<div class="links quick-edit-links">
    <?php print theme('links', array('links' => $quick_links, 'class' => 'links inline')); ?>
</div>
```

But that prints out the edit link no matter what.  What's the correct way to do this.  Ideally I'd like to have a solution that is reasonably generic and works for practically any link (e.g. node/id/delete, or admin/)  So I can use it elsewhere, but a solution which only works for this specific case would be OK.

Answer (score 4):

Now I feel silly, found an answer myself straight away, although it does only work for this specific example, I'd still be interested to see something more general.

```
<?php if (node_access('update', $node)):
    print l('edit', 'node/' . $nid . '/edit');
endif; ?>
```